# Named group in regular expression match

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to parse some source files for some standard information.

The source files could look like this:

```
// Name: BoltBait
// Title: Some cool thing
```

or

```
// Name  :
// Title : Another thing
```

or

```
// Title:
// Name:
```

etc.

The code I'm using to parse for the information looks like this:

```
Regex REName = new Regex(@"\/{2}\s*Name\s*:\s*(?<nlabel>.*)\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match mname = REName.Match(ScriptText); // entire source code file
if (mname.Success)
{
    Name.Text = mname.Groups["nlabel"].Value.Trim();
}
```

Which works fine if the field has information.  It doesn't work if the field is left blank.

For example, in the third example above, the `Title` field returns a match of "// Name:" and I want it to return the empty string.

I need help from a regex expert.

I thought the regex was too greedy, so I tried the following expression:

```
@"\/{2}\s*Name\s*:\s*(?<nlabel>.*?)\n"
```

However, it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe try `new Regex(@"\/{2}\s*Name\s*:\s*(?<nlabel>.+)\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a [class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) to avoid matching newline symbols:

```
//[\s-[\r\n]]*Name[\s-[\r\n]]*:[\s-[\r\n]]*(?<nlabel>.*)(?=\r?\n|$)
```

Note that:

- `[\s-[\r\n]]*` - Matches any whitespace excluding newline symbols (a character class subtraction is used)
- `(?=\r?\n|$)` - A positive look-ahead that checks if there is a line break or the end of the string.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%2f%5b%5cs-%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%5d*Name%5b%5cs-%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%5d*%3a%5b%5cs-%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%5d*(%3f%3cnlabel%3e.*)(%3f%3d%5cr%3f%5cn%7c%24)&i=%2f%2f+Name%3a+BoltBait%0d%0a%2f%2f+Title%3a+Some+cool+thing%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2f+Name++%3a%0d%0a%2f%2f+Title+%3a+Another+thing%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2f+Title%3a%0d%0a%2f%2f+Name%3a), output:

[image]

Comment: I just showed two of the many fields I'm grabbing.  They can be in any order and they can be there or missing.

Comment: I have edited the answer so that it could only match what you need. The regex I suggest is .NET-specific since the `[...-[...]]` is only allowed in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` includes line breaks, which is not wanted here.
It should suffice to match tabs and spaces explicitly after `:`

```
\/{2}\s*Name\s*:[\t ]*(?<nlabel>.*?)\n
```

This returns the empty string correctly in your third example (for both name and title).

Comment: I didn't know that '\s' included line breaks.  This looks promising. I'll check when I get home tonight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use an alternate in a non-capturing group to match the label from the colon to the end of the line. This matches either anything to the end of the line, or nothing.

```
var text1 = "// Name: BoltBait" + Environment.NewLine + "// Title: Some cool thing" + Environment.NewLine;
var text2 = "// Name  :" + Environment.NewLine + "// Title : Another thing" + Environment.NewLine;
var text3 = "// Title:" + Environment.NewLine + "// Name:" + Environment.NewLine;
var texts = new List<string>() { text1, text2, text3 };

var options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
var regex = new Regex("^//\\s*?Name\\s*?:(?<nlabel>(?:.*$|$))", options );

foreach (var text in texts){
    var match = regex.Match( text );

    Console.WriteLine( "|" + match.Groups["nlabel"].Value.Trim() + "|" );
}
```

Produces:

```
|BoltBait|
||
||
```

Comment: Grabbing the first appearance of a field is fine for my purposes.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the task. I've changed the code to do what I think you need ;)